# Why can I not use .AutoSize in a label

Tags: c#, wpf, word-wrap, textblock

In my program, I have a TextBlock where my result text is shown. In a textbox I can just use `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and I can scroll down if it's still too much for the textbox. Now in my TextBlock that I talked about I wanted to have the same thing and used `TextWrapping="Wrap"` again. That works except for the scrolling thing. What can I do now to let it scroll like in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following structure

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="scrView" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="100" Height="100">
  <TextBlock Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=scrView}" TextWrapping="Wrap">your text</TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```